# How can I implement a tag chooser that prevents entry of arbitrary tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to implement a tag or category selector in an HTML page.

The tags need to be supplied to the user, and they should *not* be allowed to enter an arbitrary tag.

jQuery UI supply a [very popular auto-complete implementation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple), but it appears to allow selection of arbitrary tags.

In the screenshot below, I've been allowed to select `"j"` and `"javascript"` without any special effort.

Are there any techniques, implementations, or 3rd party tools I can use to **not allow the user to enter arbitrary tags?**

Edit: My web application runs using PHP, jQuery, jQuery-UI, MySQL, and the usual front-end tools.

[image]

Comment: `should not be allowed to enter an arbitrary tag` what exactly you meant by 'arbitrary tag`??

Comment: @Bingo I mean that the input field should supply the possible options, and the user should not be able to input their own.

Comment: @Readandwhite ohh got it now, thanks. Your question made me learn many things +1 for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using an extra library is not a problem for you, Bootstrap solves your problem with a bit of JQuery help.

I have prepared a simple JSFiddle for you, where you can see it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/sgmonda/Tjbys/8/

What I have done is to prepare a text input and a `<ul>` list where your selected tags will appear. Bootstrap lets you autocomplete when writing into the input, so you have to turn default autocomplete off:

```
<input type="text" id="tags" autocomplete="off" />
<ul id="selected-tags"></ul>
```

Then you just have to add some JQuery lines to let Bootstrap autocomplete your input and add selected tags to your `<ul>` list:

```
$('#tags').typeahead({
    source: ['elem1', 'elem2', 'elem3', 'otherElem', 'oneMore'],
    updater: function (item) {
         $('#selected-tags').append('<li>' + item + '</li>');   
    }
});
```

Whenever you want you can read the list to know what elements have been selected by the user.

```
var selectedTags = [];
$('#selected-tags').each(function(){
   selectedTags.push($(this).text()); 
});
```

**EDIT**

If you want to avoid duplicated tags and add the posibility of remove them:

http://jsfiddle.net/sgmonda/JMepQ/3/

Comment: Bootstrap (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) is a JavaScript library (and optional CSS stylesheets)  written by Twitter authors, which is very useful for UIs development (like JQuery UI). In my JSFiddle it is used, as you can see in "External Resources", on the left sidebar.

Comment: I've modified your jsfiddle only very slightly to disallow duplicates: http://jsfiddle.net/JMepQ/ is there any chance I can also enable the deletion of tags?

Comment: One final thing: the updated jsFiddle disallows duplicates, and can perform deletions. However, the deletions aren't tracked. This means I can't e.g. add "elem1", delete it, and re-add it. Is this fiddle an acceptable solution to ALSO detect the deletions? --> http://jsfiddle.net/8WkXA/

Comment: No, your last fiddle is not correct because it allows multiple selections of every tag. Don't worry, I have updated my solution with your request and here is the final result: http://jsfiddle.net/sgmonda/JMepQ/3/

Comment: This absolutely has all the features I wanted. Really pleased, because I've also been made aware of Bootstrap. Many thanks!